# How to pass string arguments in Python function via C++

Tags: python, c++

[Image shows the output. I am expecting "Hai" to be printed. But its printing some number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDInI.png)How to pass string argument to python function via c++

I tried below code. It can pass double, float, int , bool values. But when it pass string value its printed as numbers which seems to be a memory location
Python.py is my script file name

```py
class Adder:
    # Constructor
    def __init__(self):
        self.sum = 0

    def disp(self, param1):
        print("Parameter is: ", param1)
```

```
void ExecutePyMethodeWitStringArg()
{
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pClass, *pInstance;

    // Initialize the Python interpreter
    Py_Initialize();

    // Build the name object
    pName = PyUnicode_FromString("Python");
    // Load the module object
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    // pDict is a borrowed reference
    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
    // Build the name of a callable class
    pClass = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "Adder");


    // Create an instance of the class
    if (PyCallable_Check(pClass))
    {
        pInstance = PyObject_CallObject(pClass, NULL);

        PyObject_CallMethod(pInstance, "disp", "(i)", "Hai");


    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot instantiate the Python class" << std::endl;
    }
    std::getchar();
    Py_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: What *are* you doing? What is your C++ [mcve]? Please refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Above is the code. I just want to pass a string to python function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a mismatching format specifier and argument type:

```
    PyObject_CallMethod(pInstance, "disp", "(i)", "Hai");
```

According to [the `Py_BuildValue` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#c.Py_BuildValue) the format `"(i)"` would be for a tuple of integers, not a string.

You need to use `"s"` for the format for a null-terminated C string.